# CSS - Grid positioning if element does not exist

Tags: css, sass, css-grid

Is it possible to prepare the grid in such a way that if a given element is not present, it inserts the elements that are available? For example, if there is no first element, then in the first row we have "item middle item"?

```
 <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="middle"></div>
 </div>

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 20px;

    grid-template-areas:
    "first first first"
    ". middle ."
    ". . .";
}
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oA6B.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following, that should do it:

```
.item:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

You can see in this example, everything will back-fill into empty grid cells.

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 20px;

    grid-template-areas:
    "first first first"
    ". middle ."
    ". . .";
}

.item:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
 <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="middle">m</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but in this case I will not receive any "item".

Comment: If you populate the item with data, you will.

Comment: My example, was just an example to show how "middle" will back-fill. If you put any data in any of the "item" div elements, then they will block "middle" from moving back up the grid. Another option for you to consider: if you need to check very specific "item" divs, then you can increase specificity of the "empty" selector. And, in those specific cases, you could update the div's `grid-area` property. Options are kind of endless.

Comment: In this case, the point is that the elements appear from the loops. Thus, a given element, as in the example of first, may not appear at all, and thus I cannot check if it is empty. Grid-area is definitely a good clue, but it must work on the principle that if there is no first element at all, put elements from the next row in grid area.